# Flask deja de responder tras unas pocas peticiones

Tags: mysql, python, reactjs, flask, nginx

Tengo una aplicación de flask que hace peticiones a un servidor mysql. Funciona bien cuando hago las peticiones desde el navegador o desde algún cliente rest como insmonia. Además he hecho deploy con uwsgi y nginx siguiendo el tutorial de digitalOcean. El problema es que quiero hacer las peticiones desde una aplicación de react. Esta aplicación hace tres peticiones casi a la vez en cuanto arranca y aparentemente esto bloquea el servidor de flask y deja de funcionar. Todas las petciones que hago después se quedan cargando sin devolver ningún resultado.

En algunas ocasiones cuando reviso el estado del servidor flask con systemctl status me devuelve el siguiente error:

```
  File "/home/javi/code/new_spoti/api/apienv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", l>
    result = self._handle_result(self._send_cmd(ServerCmd.QUERY, query))
  File "/home/javi/code/new_spoti/api/apienv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", l>
    return self._handle_ok(packet)
  File "/home/javi/code/new_spoti/api/apienv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", l>
    ok_pkt = self._protocol.parse_ok(packet)
  File "/home/javi/code/new_spoti/api/apienv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mysql/connector/protocol.py", lin>
    ok_packet['warning_count']) = struct_unpack('<HH', packet[0:4])
struct.error: unpack requires a buffer of 4 bytes
[pid: 8922|app: 0|req: 1/6] 192.168.1.30 () {42 vars in 641 bytes} [Fri May 22 09:39:32 2020] GET /api/gen>
```

En otras ocasiones ni siquiera devuelve ningún error. A todo esto se le suma que a veces en la misma carpeta donde tengo el proyecto de flask se crea un archivo "core" que no tiene permisos ni de lectura ni de escritura. Cuando lo abro parece algún tipo archivo binario con pero con comentarios explicando el funcionamiento de algunas librerías de python como os en ocasiones con un tono burlesco haciendo preguntas retóricas. Me ha salido varias veces y cuando lo quito no pasa nada.

No sé donde puede estar el error porque la base de datos sigue funcionando después de que flask se trabe. He estado pensando incluso en reescribir la aplicación en ruby on rails porque no encuentro el fallo.

Comment: El problema puede ser el threading: múltiples threads utilizan una sola conexión lo que lleva a conflictos. Cuáles son tu configuración uwsgi y Dockerfile reales? Aquellos en github no parecen estar funcionando.

Comment: @themylogin No he hecho deploy en docker todavía, está funcionando como un servicio más en mi ordenador porque no sé si el método que usé para hacer deploy es el más óptimo para hacerlo en un contenedor. La configuración de uwsgi es la que está en config.ini, no hay nada más. Si he entendido bien, con aumentar el número de threads de uwsgi debería funcionar bien?

Comment: No, es al revés, tu código actual solo puede funcionar bien con `threads = 1`, pero es así por defecto. El archivo `core` aparece cuando python (u otro software) falla, esto puede ser un signo de problemas con la instalación local de Python en lugar de un problema con tu código.

Comment: @themylogin como puedo habilitar el uso de más threads?

Comment: Utiliza una biblioteca especial, por exemplo https://pypi.org/project/flask-mysqlpool/ Gestionar conexiones de bases de datos es una tarea no trivial

Comment: Muchas gracias @themylogin, esa librería arregló el fallo. No entendía como funcionaban las conexiones con la base de datos, pensaba que con una bastaba pero ahora ya comprendo el fallo.